# fitness.course object can't draw the route on facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I try to build an app with sharing feature to draw the route on facebook as fitness post.
I think all the things has been covered to draw the route on the map.

```
<!-- Facebook opne graph meta data start -->

<!-- Standard Open Graph object properties -->
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="FACEBOOK_APP_ID" /> 
<meta property="og:type"        content="fitness.course" /> 
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://sample.url" /> 
<meta property="og:title"       content="User's Diary" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="User rode 8.0km for 11m 36s" />
<meta property="og:image"       content="http://14.63.224.224/img/logo@220.png" /> 

<!-- Other Open Graph properties -->
<meta property="fitness:distance:value" content="8.0" /> 
<meta property="fitness:distance:units" content="km" /> 
<meta property="fitness:duration:value" content="636" /> 
<meta property="fitness:duration:units" content="s" /> 
<meta property="fitness:speed:value"    content="12.3065" /> 
<meta property="fitness:speed:units"    content="m/s" /> 
<meta property="fitness:calories:value" content="181.7" /> 

<!-- ActivityDataPoint 0 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.51844" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="126.9918" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="16.61127" />

<!-- ActivityDataPoint 1 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.51769" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="126.9908" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="13.85767" /><

!-- ActivityDataPoint 2 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.51714" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="126.9897" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="22.03296" />

<!-- ActivityDataPoint 3 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.51693" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="126.9887" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="23.54077" />

<!-- ActivityDataPoint 4 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.51688" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="126.9878" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="27.52216" />

<!-- Facebook opne graph meta data end -->
```

My questions are

1. What kind of metrics property do I need to draw the proper route as Nike Run does?
2. Is there certain sort of order to list meta data for the location values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself.

To draw the route on the facebook map(?) you must have location(lat, long), distance(value, unit), pace (value, unit) for each Activity Data Point. And since your riding, running and whatever course usually do have a lot of Geopoints, you'd always better have an separate meta-data page for the course. Facebook actually recommends it. And it is also very important to use PROPER UNITS but sometimes you can't find one. Then use m/s instead mph. Facebook will take care of things to show the value with MPH.

I attached the sample code below. Hope it help someone like me.

COURSE OBJECT HTML

```
<!-- Standard Open Graph object properties -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="FACEBOOK_APP_ID" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="fitness.course" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="SAMPLE_CANONICAL_URL" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="ABC's Diary" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="ABC's burned 0 kcal for 3m 30s. The best speed was 0.0. " />
<meta property="og:image" content="SAMPLE_CANONICAL_URL/img/img.png" /> 

<!-- Other Open Graph properties -->
<meta property="fitness:distance:value" content="0.0" /> 
<meta property="fitness:distance:units" content="km" /> 
<meta property="fitness:calories" content="0" /> 
<meta property="fitness:duration:value" content="150" /> 
<meta property="fitness:duration:units" content="s" /> 
<meta property="fitness:speed:value" content="0.0000" /> 
<meta property="fitness:speed:units" content="m/s" /> 

<link rel="opengraph" href="SAMPLE_CANONICAL_URL"/>
```

GEOPOINT OBJECT (rel="opengraph")

```
<!-- Special type for an Open Graph metadata object -->
<meta property="og:type" content="metadata" />

<!-- Pointer to the source URL -->
<link rel="origin" href="http://SAMPLE_CANONICAL_URL_FOR_COURSE" />

<!-- ActivityDataPoint 0 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.43357" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="127.1585" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="110.3485" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:distance:value" content="0" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:distance:units" content="km" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:pace:value" content="0" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:pace:units" content="s/m" />

<!-- ActivityDataPoint 1 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.43357" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="127.1585" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="108.1185" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:distance:value" content="0" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:distance:units" content="km" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:pace:value" content="0" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:pace:units" content="s/m" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of an old question but for people looking for solution:

You should add fitness:metrics:timestamp property for each point in order to see route:

```
<!-- ActivityDataPoint 0 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.51844" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="126.9918" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="16.61127" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:timestamp" content="2011-01-26T00:00" />

<!-- ActivityDataPoint 1 -->
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:latitude" content="37.51769" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:longitude" content="126.9908" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:location:altitude" content="13.85767" />
<meta property="fitness:metrics:timestamp" content="2011-01-26T00:30" />
```